# How to compile TypeScript's export default into exports = xxx

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, module

In TypeScript code, I export a class like this:

```
export default class World {
}
```

But I found that TypeScript compile it into:

```
exports.default = class World {
}
```

So how to compile it like this:

```
exports = class World {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the syntax `export =`:

```
export = class World {
}
```

See also: [The handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require).

Note that this is not compatible with ES6 modules. This kind of code can never be compiled as a native ES6 module.

## Why an `export default` cannot be compiled to `exports =`

The TypeScript compiler generates a member `default` in the formats CommonJS and AMD because it is the way the standard works. In the ES6 standard:

> There’s nothing magic about a default export; it’s just like any other export, except it’s named `"default"`.

Source: [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/), from Mozilla.

Comment: Then is it possible to make `export default xxx` compiled into `module.exports = xxx` ?

Answer (score -2):

In compiler settings try,

```
{
    module = "CommonJS",
    moduleResolution = "Node"
}
```

It should compile to `module.exports = ...`